# Using Jquery to only allow certain characters, with error message

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have been looking around and am a little confused on how to us jQuery to only allow certain characters being entered, and if an invalid character is entered, then I want to have a message saying sorry, only "blah blah blah is allowed."

I have half of it, to only allow certain characters on this input field,

```
<p><label>First Name: <input type="text" name="First"  size="20" maxlength= "40" class="First"  /></label></p>
```

so for my jquery I have

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
$('.First').bind('keyup blur',function(){ 
    $(this).val( $(this).val().replace(/[^A-Za-z]/g,'') ); }
);

    </script>
```

However, say if I enter a number, I would like a pop up to occur to explain only letters are allowed. I looked around but honestly I am new to jquery, and am not sure how to do this.

Another thing I was wondering, if I did not have `class="First"` and only had `name="First"` in the input part, how would I reference that with jQuery? if I get rid of `class="First"` then it does not work, does jQuery require class to identify whats its acting upon?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The on blur would be the way to go, and you could use RegExp to find and test the string to see if any illegal characters are within it.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $('.First').bind('keyup blur',function(){
        //Illegal character regex
        var regIllegal = /[0-9]/
        if(regIllegal.test($(this).val())){
            alert('Only letters allowed!');
        }
        $(this).val( $(this).val().replace(/[^A-Za-z]/g,'') ); }
    );
</script>
```

For the second part of your question, you can select the input without the class, but it would need to be modified as a css selector like so:

```
$('input[name="First"]').bind( ... )
```

Please note that I didn't test this code so it might need a bit of debugging :)

Comment: Thank you! Cleared things up